# How to import the photo albums of a fan page on facebook C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I used the tutorial in [this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-Facebook-Album-Photos-and-display-as-Image-Gallery-in-ASPNet.aspx) to download the photos from a Facebook page, but I need to import pictures from a **specific fan page** and display them on my site, have created an application on facebook and got the App_Key and App_Secret. How can I do this? Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me/albums");` you should replace `me` with either the specific Page identifier (e.g. `CocaCola`), or the Page ID (e.g. `262355423960836` for CocaCola).